# ViewDidLoad() method called every time in xCode 9.4 and iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode9.4

Whenever we `present` or `push` from `SourceViewController` to `DestinationViewController`, `ViewDidLoad()` method called every time in `DestinationViewController` in `xCode 9.4` and `iOS 11` or later. And when we pop or dismiss from `DestinationViewController` to `SourceViewController`, `viewDidLoad()` method not called.

Comment: See viewDidLoad called only once when you create the VC object. Every time you create a new VC object it gets called.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not supposed to be called when popping or dismissing, so the behavior is correct

Comment: @vivekDas, debug and check out ViewDidLoad() called without creating any object. If project will be large and method called every time, that time we get memory and loading issues. So i want to sort out that issue.

Comment: Its not possible that ViewDidLoad will get called without creating and showing the VC. You are checking something wrong. Check the below article.  
https://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/ios-essentials-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/

Comment: @vivekDas viewDidLoad is not supposed to be called every time when present or push, first time it should, but not every time. in my case its get called every time. in xCode 8 and iOS 10 it wasn't called every time but now in xCode 9.4 and iOS 11 its called every time.

Comment: post your code , you may be creating the new Instance .

Comment: @DivyaPatel : See the updated answer .

Comment: Add your code how you present your VC.

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidload method only called only when the view loads first time. When you present or push it loads the view so, it calls viewdidload. But when you pop it release the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the lifecycle of `UIViewController`.

- `ViewDidLoad` - Called when you create the class and load from xib. (Either present or push) This method called for initial setup and only one time called.
- `ViewWillAppear` - Called right before your view appears, this will be called every time your view is about to appear on the screen.
- `ViewDidAppear` - Called after the view appears - great place to start
  an animations or the loading of external data from an API. This will be also called every time after `ViewWillAppear` when view appeared on the screen.
- `ViewWillDisappear/DidDisappear` - Same idea as ViewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear only when view is about to dismiss or pop.
- `ViewDidUnload/ViewDidDispose` - In Swift or Objective C, this is where you do
  your clean-up and release of stuff, but this is handled automatically
  so not much you really need to do here.

Read Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) for details.